# How to convert arbitrary time to NSDate to format it using NSDateFormatter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Let's say I have an `NSString` containing `15:00 PM`. I am trying to use `NSDateFormatter` to format it to display

> 3:00 PM

However, when I try to print out the formatted string, it's `null`.

```
NSString *string = @"15:00 PM";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [ [NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
NSDate *time = [formatter dateFromString:string];

string = [formatter stringFromDate:time];

NSLog(@"%@", string);
```

How should the string be assigned to properly format it?

Comment: I guess "15:00 PM" is not valid because 15:00 is in 24-hour format and should not contain any AM/PM part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following code,

```
NSString *string = @"15:00";
NSDateFormatter *inputDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[inputDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

NSDate *date = [inputDateFormatter dateFromString:string];

NSDateFormatter *outputDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[outputDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
NSString *outputString = [outputDateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: this is giving me a null output when I try to NSLog outputString

Comment: thanks Rahul, but how can I remove the 0 at the beginning of 03:00?

Answer (score 1):

I am in accord with Mikhail comment, you should write the pattern in this way:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm a"];
```

The format string uses the format patterns from the Unicode Technical Standard # 35 ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)), for more information about date and time format in iOS, you can have a look [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the screenshot which says that 24 hours format does not contain am/pm part:-
[image]

Use valid date format and then use the below code for setting to 12 hours time format:-

```
NSDate *time = [formatter dateFromString:string];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
```